# How to debug xtend code in IntelliJ + Gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, xtend

I have just started to learn Xtend (http://xtend-lang.org/) and try to write a small app in IntelliJ 2016 based on a Gradle project using the Xtext/Xtend 2.10.0 plugins from the standard repository. The problem is that I cannot debug my Xtend code. Breakpoints are all ignored although debugging of Java code works. Debugging Xtend code only works if I use the IntelliJ wizard and create a standard IntelliJ project without using Gradle. I don't know how to fix this? Do I miss something? Does debugging works different in a Gradle project?

Here my Gradle file:

```
group 'GradleXtend'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.xtext.xtend'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib:2.10.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.xtext:xtext-gradle-plugin:1.0.12'
    }
}

xtend {
    debugger {
        //how to install debug info into generated Java code
        //SMAP adds Xtend debug info on top of Java
        //PRIMARY makes Xtend the only debug info (throws away Java line numbers)
        //default is SMAP for Java projects and PRIMARY for Android
        sourceInstaller = 'SMAP' //or 'PRIMARY' or 'NONE'
        //whether to hide synthetic variables in the debugger
        hideSyntheticVariables = false
    }
}
```

My Xtend file:

```
package HelloWorld

class HelloWorld2 {

  def static void main(String[] args) {
        println("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using IntelliJ with xtend, but in Eclipse there is a difference between gradle setup and eclipse setup. Xtend gradle plugin is smart enough to do both, but it might be missing some integration with IntelliJ (as it is all quite new port). Can you try, after initializing gradle project, to add some kind of xtend support manually by enabling plugin? If it works, then it is probably just deficiency in current version of xtend gradle plugin.

Comment: did you tell the xtend gradle plugin to produce the metadata needed for debugging? i am not sure what the default config is http://xtext.github.io/xtext-gradle-plugin/xtend.html

Comment: @ChristianDietrich: I have add the debugger settings above but no success... :(

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski: My project file are created by the IntelliJ wizzard and I explicitly tell IntelliJ to use Xtend. I have tried different settings but it does not work.

Comment: I think you will have best chance of getting answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xtend-lang - all the xtend creators are there. Not many people use it in intellij yet.